# Connecting to Exchange Online with a Certificate and C#

Tags: c#, office365, exchange-server

Anyone using c# to connect to Exchange online? I am running into a problem that I can't seem to make progress on.

I have the following snippet of code trying to connect to exchange online:

```
public Runspace getSpace() {
    String schema = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange";
    Uri server = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/PowerShell");
    string certificateThumbprint = "thumbprint";

    WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(server, schema, certificateThumbprint);
    Runspace rsp = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo );
    rsp.Open();
    return rsp;
}
```

Which results in:

> System.Management.Automation.Remoting.PSRemotingTransportException:
>  Connecting to remote server outlook.office365.com failed with the following error message :  For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
> at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.AsyncResult.EndInvoke()

I know the cert is working because when I do the following I am able to connect:

```
Connect-ExchangeOnline -AppId "application guid" -Organization "tenent.onmicrosoft.com" -CertificateThumbprint "thumbprint"
```

Any ideas on what I could try next? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For connecting to O365 with certificate thumbprint I use the following code, which works:

```
using (Runspace remoteRunspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace()){
remoteRunspace.Open();

using (PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create())
{
    powershell.Runspace = remoteRunspace;
    powershell.AddCommand("Import-Module");
    powershell.AddParameter("Name", "ExchangeOnlineManagement");
    powershell.Invoke();

    powershell.Commands.Clear();

    powershell.AddCommand("Connect-ExchangeOnline");
    powershell.AddParameter("AppId", "");
    powershell.AddParameter("CertificateThumbprint", "");
    powershell.AddParameter("Organization", "");
    powershell.Invoke();

    powershell.Commands.Clear();

    powershell.AddCommand("Get-EXOMailbox");
    powershell.AddParameter("Identity", "");
    powershell.Invoke();

    Collection<PSObject> results = powershell.Invoke();

    powershell.Commands.Clear();

    powershell.AddCommand("Disconnect-ExchangeOnline");
    powershell.Invoke();
}
remoteRunspace.Close();}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [EWS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/explore-the-ews-managed-api-ews-and-web-services-in-exchange) or [Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-the-api) instead.

Comment: Unfortunately neither of those will work since I need to connect for administrative purposes and those features don't appear to be possible.