# Exchange Online PowerShell V2- Token authentication with refresh token

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server

I need to implement the new Exchange Online PowerShell V2 module as the basic authentication is EOL. I was not able to find a suitable method for our use case as I have a service which executes automated PS scripts without any user interaction. I've searched for a way to use token authentication in a way that first I would authenticate the user and store the access token and use it for the automated calls. All of this of course with the refresh token mechanism. I've failed to find such an option.

Can anybody help to find an alternative without storing the user's password on the server?

Thanks

Comment: I've recently completed rewriting some Exchange based scripts here that were using basic auth for exactly the same reason and settled on creating an app registration in Azure AD, granted it the relevant exchange permissions and then use certificate-based authentication to connect. Would using certificate-based authentication be suitable for you? More info on this can be found here: [App-only authentication for unattended scripts in the EXO V2 module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/app-only-auth-powershell-v2?view=exchange-ps)

Comment: I've found this option as well, investigated it's usage as well.  I just thought that maybe there is another, a better way maybe...

Comment: Perhaps using the [MSAL.PS](https://github.com/AzureAD/MSAL.PS) module would be helpful in that case? Once you've made an initial token request, the token (and refresh token) would be stored in the MSAL token cache, and you should then be able to reconnect using the `-Silent` parameter to automatically use the cached tokens. The help shows the `-Silent` parameter is used for: **Attempts to acquire an access token from the user token cache**, and [this MSAL.PS GitHub issue](https://github.com/AzureAD/MSAL.PS/issues/11) confirms the refresh tokens are stored in the cache

Comment: you mean that I can use EXO V2 powershell modules with MSAL.PS? I used MSAL.net in one of my projects but this was to gain access to graph api or EWS with token authentication

Comment: Ahh, I think that's where I'm getting confused, apologies. Looking back on my scripts, I was using it to connect to the graph api, rather than EXO v2. I've been digging around and can't find a way to use Connect-ExchangeOnline (or the underlying New-ExoPsSession) cmdlets with an access token.

Comment: @NiMux: I've tried to implement the certificate based authentication with C# and remote PS but run into the same issue as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71784345/connecting-to-exchange-online-with-a-certificate-and-c-sharp
did you  succeed with your code using C# and Modern Auth?