# Exchange Online Powershell BasicAuthToOAuth not working with WSManConnectionInfo

Tags: c#, powershell, oauth-2.0, office365, powershell-remoting

Our code currently uses WSManConnectionInfo class to connect to O365. We use basic auth and are trying to upgrade to modern auth. I turned off basic auth in my tenant. Following this guide here, https://www.michev.info/Blog/Post/2997/connecting-to-exchange-online-powershell-via-client-secret-fl..., I am able to connect successfully in PowerShell by getting an access token and using New-PSSession cmdlet. I use the following commands:

```
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\AzureAD\2.0.2.140\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll'
 
$authContext45 = New-Object "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext" -ArgumentList " https://login.windows.net/mytenant.onmicrosoft.com"
$secret = Get-ChildItem cert://localmachine/my/thumbprint
$CAC = [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.ClientAssertionCertificate]::new(appId,$secret)
$authenticationResult = $authContext45.AcquireTokenAsync("https://outlook.office365.com",$CAC)

$token = $authenticationResult.Result.AccessToken
$Authorization = "Bearer {0}" -f $Token
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Authorization -Force
$Ctoken = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList "OAuthUser@tenantGUID",$Password
 
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/PowerShell-LiveId?BasicAuthToOAuthConversion=true -Credential $Ctoken -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection -Verbose
Import-PSSession $Session
```

However, when I try to use C# WSManConnectionInfo to do the same thing, I get this strange error whenever I try to open the runspace:

System.Management.Automation.Remoting.PSRemotingTransportException
HResult=0x80131501
Message=Connecting to remote server outlook.office365.com failed with the following error message : The WS-Management service cannot process the request. Cannot find the https://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange session configuration in the WSMan: drive on the outlook.office365.com computer. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
Here is the code:

```
    public static Collection<PSObject> GetUsersUsingOAuthPublic()
    {
        var authContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/mytenant.onmicrosoft.com");
        X509Store certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);

        certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, certThumbprint, false);
        certStore.Close();
        var cac = new ClientAssertionCertificate(appId, certCollection[0]);
        var authResult = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://outlook.office365.com", cac);

        var token = authResult.Result.AccessToken;
        string auth = string.Format("Bearer {0}", token);
        System.Security.SecureString password = new System.Security.SecureString();

        foreach (char c in auth)
        {
            password.AppendChar(c);
        }

        PSCredential psCredential = new PSCredential(string.Format("OAuthUser@{0}", tenantId), password);

        WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(
            new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid?BasicAuthToOAuthConversion=true"),
            "https://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange",
            psCredential
            );
        connectionInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Basic;
        connectionInfo.SkipCACheck = true;
        connectionInfo.SkipCNCheck = true;

        using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo))
        {
            return GetUserInformation(10, runspace);
        }
    }
```

I open the runspace like so:

```
    public static Collection<PSObject> GetUserInformation(int count, Runspace runspace)
    {
        using (PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            powershell.AddCommand("Get-Users");
            powershell.AddParameter("ResultSize", count);
            runspace.Open();
            powershell.Runspace = runspace;
            return powershell.Invoke();
        }
    }
```

The exception:
[Image of exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2gDc.png)

Comment: At your link, see comments from Anishka on July 10, 2020.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've been working on this issue as well and we were able to get it to work. In this test case we used a secret instead of a certificate for the accessToken, but that shouldn't matter.

First difference is the uri should look like this:

```cs
Uri psURI = new($"https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid?BasicAuthToOAuthConversion=true&email=SystemMailbox%7bbb558c35-97f1-4cb9-8ff7-d53741dc928c%7d%40{msDomain}");
```

The second change is the schema, with this change, you don't pass the full url for the schema, only the last part:

```cs
WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new(psURI, "Microsoft.Exchange", psCredential)
{
    AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Basic,    
    SkipCACheck = true,
    SkipCNCheck = true
};
```

Instead of passing in "https://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange" just pass in "Microsoft.Exchange"

Here is the full code that allowed us to run Get-Mailbox against a tenant with basic auth disabled:

```cs
string clientId = "";
string tenantId = "";
string secret = "";
string upn = "user@yourdomain.com";
string msDomain = "YOURDOMAIN.onmicrosoft.com";


IConfidentialClientApplication thisApp = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
    .WithClientSecret(secret)
    .WithAuthority($"https://login.windows.net/{msDomain}/")
    .Build();
AuthenticationResult accessToken = await thisApp.AcquireTokenForClient(new[] { $"https://outlook.office365.com/.default" }).ExecuteAsync();

//Bearer Header
string auth = $"Bearer {accessToken.AccessToken}";
SecureString password = GetSecureString(auth);

PSCredential psCredential = new($"OAuthUser@{tenantId}", password);

Uri psURI = new("https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid?BasicAuthToOAuthConversion=true&email=SystemMailbox%7bbb558c35-97f1-4cb9-8ff7-d53741dc928c%7d%40{domain}");

WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new(psURI, "Microsoft.Exchange", psCredential)
{
    AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Basic,    
    SkipCACheck = true,
    SkipCNCheck = true,
};

using Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo);
runspace.Open();
using PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.Runspace = runspace;

ps.AddCommand("Get-Mailbox");
ps.AddParameter("Identity", upn);

var results = await ps.InvokeAsync();
```

Comment: This works, I only changed the schema in my code to "Microsoft.Exchange". How did you figure it out?

Comment: @onyx12 I was debugging happened to look at my connectionInfo object and noticed the schema property showed as: "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/https://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange"

Comment: Hi @sysnickm, on your code, I see this one "Uri psURI = new("https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid?BasicAuthToOAuthConversion=true&email=SystemMailbox%7bbb558c35-97f1-4cb9-8ff7-d53741dc928c%7d%40lukydev.onmicrosoft.com");" May I know what is bb558c35-97f1-4cb9-8ff7-d53741dc928c mean? Thanks. I'm facing an issue with onyx12.

Comment: @DonLee That is the well-known GUID for the system account that exists in each tenant. It is the same for everybody.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is not supported by Microsoft. To connect to Exchange Online with MFA you should use one of the supported methods described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/exchange/connect-to-exchange-online-powershell?view=exchange-ps

Please check my answer for connecting using the  certificate thumbprint in a form of unattended script which is the closest to what you would like to achieve:
[Connecting to Exchange Online with a Certificate and C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71784345/connecting-to-exchange-online-with-a-certificate-and-c-sharp/73606983#73606983)

Your other options for connecting are:

- Interactive scripting using browser-based single sign-on
- Device-based log in
- Inline credentials

all of those options are described in my link above

Comment: I am not connecting with MFA though, just trying to use modern authentication (i.e. OAuth based). As for CBA based, I want to use Credentials based rather than CBA.

Comment: are you aware that the basic authentication will be turned off by end of September by Microsoft? I was facing the same like you and was forced to upgrade to modern  authentication because of the decommissioning process

Comment: You can still use credentials based auth with modern authentication (i.e. exchange V2 module) with the Credential parameter. It does the OAuth2 token acquiring stuff behind the scenes. I've tested this in my tenant. MFA != modern authentication.